# What is the access time of the python 'in' operator for various data types?

Tags: python, time-complexity

As the title says, I'm wondering how fast the 'in' operator is for various data structures. For example, for a dictionary, since the dictionary acts as a hash map, I know the access time is amortized constant, O(1).

What about in a list or substrings in strings?

```
5 in [1,2,3,4,5]
'hello' in 'hello world'
```

My gut feeling tells me that these would be O(n) access time, but maybe in the list case, maybe python backs list elements with a hash set to speed the process.

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity is documented on the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

List membership testing takes O(n) time; the same applies to any of the sequence types (so strings are O(n) as well). For sets and dictionaries, membership testing is O(1) constant time.

Comment: Thanks for that link --- I had no idea these were all documented somewhere.